# Match 2 large csv based on column?

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk

I have 2 large csv as following:

csv1.txt

```
ID,Name
a0BQ0007OeSDSA,John
a0BQ0013OeBMAU,May
a0BQ0003OeAASA,Marry
a0BQ0032OeBNGG,Peter
....
```

csv2.txt

```
ID,Email
a0BQfg343eBMAU,no@email.com
a0BQ0033OeAASA,Mar3ry@email.com
a0BQ0007OeSDSA,Johsdn@email.com
a0BQ0032OeBNGG,Peter@email.com
...
```

Output: i want match csv2 to csv1 and output the one has same ID

csv3.txt

```
John,Johsdn@email.com
Peter,Peter@email.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Perl solution. It reads the emails from `csv2.txt` first and stores them in a hash for fast lookup. Then `csv1.txt` is read, and the email for each name is fetched from the hash and printed with the name.

Names are ignored if their ID has no entry in the hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'csv2.txt' or die $!;

my %emails;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $email) = split /,/;
  $emails{$id} = $email;
}

open $fh, '<', 'csv1.txt' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $name) = split /,/;
  next unless exists $emails{$id};
  my $email = $emails{$id} or next;
  print "$name,$email\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Name,Email
John,Johsdn@email.com
Peter,Peter@email.com
```

Comment: Nice solution. I am still learning `perl` and had a question. What's the benefit of `or next` in the line `my $email = $emails{$id} or next;`. If the `id` is not in the hash we skip the line anyways, isn't it?

Comment: @jaypal: Yes, if the value of the assignment is *false* (`undef`, `0`, or `""`) then the `next` is executed which skips over the `print`. If it is *true* then the print statement will executed. Note that accessing a non-existent hash element returns `undef`.

Comment: Thanks, @Borodin it's clear now. I removed the email from one of the matching id and understood your clear and crisp explanation. Thanks again! +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) command, but since the data files are not in sorted order based on the ID column, you must also use the [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) command plus Bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) plus the [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) command to skip the header line.

```
join -t, -o1.2,2.2 <(sed 1d csv1.txt | sort) <(sed 1d csv2.txt | sort)
```

For your given inputs, this yields your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{$1=a[$1];print}' csv1.txt csv2.txt
Name,Email
John,Johsdn@email.com
Peter,Peter@email.com
```

**or**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a)&&$1=a[$1]' csv1.txt csv2.txt
```

Comment: If you don't want the header then put `NR>1`. That is, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR&&NR>1{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a)&&$1=a[$1]' csv1.txt csv2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Pure shell

```
while IFS=, read -r id1 name
do
   while IFS=, read -r id2 email
   do
      if [ "$id1" =  "$id2" ]; then
         echo "$name,$email"
      fi
   done < csv2.txt
done < csv1.txt

Name,Email
John,Johsdn@email.com
Peter,Peter@email.com
```

Comment: ha, an `On2` solution in the shell

Comment: I didn't get your comments, can you explain more?